# How to return all of elements from function?

Tags: python, json, ansible

I'm trying to create an Ansible module to use Batfish inside an Ansible playbook.

I'm comparing JSON values with defined variables in function. But it can compare only one JSON value and variable in the function. How do I use loop and return?

I have already tried extract values from each JSON and tried to compare with defined variable.

```py
import json
json_list = {"batfish_result": [
        {
            "Action": {
                "0": "DENY"
            },
            "Line_Content": {
                "0": "no-match"
            }
        },

       {
            "Action": {
                "0": "PERMIT"
            },
            "Line_Content": {
                "0": "permit    10.20.0.0 255.255.255.0"

            }
       }
     ]
   }


def main(json_list):
    PASS = 'PASS'
    FAIL = 'FAIL'
    result = {}
    result_list = []
    action_num_list = []
    condition_list = ['permit', 'permit']


    jsons = json_list["batfish_result"]
    for j in jsons:
        print(j)
        action = j['Action']
        action_num = action["0"]
        action_num_list.append(action_num)

    for con in condition_list:

          for action in action_num_list:

            if action == con.upper():

                result_list.append(PASS)
                result['msg'] = result_list

            else:

                result_list.append(FAIL)
                result['msg'] = result_list

    return result

main(json_list)
```

It returns

```py
{'msg': ['PASS', 'PASS']}
```

It should be comparing each action with each condition variable like this.

```
{ "msg": ['FAIL', 'PASS'] }
```

Comment: Add a couple of pretty print instructions to your program to print out values of variables in order to debug it. F.ex. preceeding the `if`: `pprint(action); pprint(con.upper())`. You'll need to include the `pprint` module to use `pprint`.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek 
So I debug and fixed a part of code. The result is like this;
'DENY'
'PERMIT'
'PERMIT'
'PERMIT'
{'msg': ['PASS', 'PASS']}

this looks like comparing 'DENY' with 'PERMIT' and 'PERMIT' with 'PERMIT' so the msg supposed be show {'msg': ['FAIL', 'PASS']}. Why it cannot comparing properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it like this;

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_list = {"batfish_result": [
        {
            "Action": {
                "0": "DENY"
            },
            "Line_Content": {
                "0": "no-match"
            }
        },

       {
            "Action": {
                "0": "PERMIT"
            },
            "Line_Content": {
                "0": "permit    10.20.0.0 255.255.255.0"

       }
  }
]
            }


def main(json_list):
    PASS = "PASS"
    FAIL = "FAIL"
    result = {}
    result_list = []
    action_num_list = []
    condition_list = ["permit", "permit"]

    jsons = json_list["batfish_result"]

    for j in jsons:
        action = j['Action']
        action_num = action["0"]
        action_num_list.append(action_num)
        #[DENY, PERMIT]

    for con in condition_list:
         con = con

    #for action in action_num_list:
    for x, y in zip(condition_list, action_num_list):

        if y == x.upper():

            result_list.append(PASS)
            result['msg'] = result_list

        #if pprint(y) != pprint(x.upper()):
        else:

            result_list.append(FAIL)
            result['msg'] = result_list

    return result_list

main(json_list)
```

Because pprint always returns 'None'. So I had to remove pprint after debug and also I used loop too much.